# Initiating a dependent QCombobox with PyQt5 in python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox

I am learning to work with PyQt5 and want to add a dependent QComboBox.
The items of the Combobox should be a list of the files in the directory.
The function get_files() reads the files in the directory and returns them as a list.

However the QCombobox only shows these items if I run the script in debug mode.
Why is this happening?

Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
import time

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(700, 681)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

self.B_SOFT = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.B_SOFT.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 150, 360, 50))
        self.B_SOFT.setObjectName("B_SOFT")

        xlsx,SOFTS = get_files()
        [self.B_SOFT.addItem(x) for x in SOFTS]

def get_files():
    import os; import numpy as np
    entries = os.listdir()
    msk = ['.xls' in x for x in entries]
    xlsx = [x for i,x in enumerate(entries) if msk[i]]
    names = [x.replace('EPB_SOFTWARE__','').replace('.xlsx','') for x in xlsx]
    return xlsx,names

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What do you mean with "only shows these items if I run the script in debug mode"? And to what "debug mode" are you referring? And what happens otherwise?